# AngularFire service not returning values?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

My very simple data model:

- Partners

  - Name
  - OrigBal

And this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="PartnerCtrl">

    <div>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.Name}} - {{item.OrigBal}}</li>
    </div>


    <script>
        var app = angular.module("bastion", ["firebase"]);
        app.constant('FIREBASE_URI', 'https://notpublic.firebaseio.com/Partners');

        app.controller('PartnerCtrl', [
            '$scope', 'PartnerService', function($scope, PartnerService) {
                $scope.newItem = { name: '', OrigBal: 0 };
                $scope.currentItem = null;

                $scope.items = PartnerService.getItems();

                $scope.addItem = function() {
                    PartnerService.addItem(angular.copy($scope.newItem));
                    $scope.newItem = { name: '', OrigBal: 0 };
                };

                $scope.updateItem = function(id) {
                    PartnerService.updateItem(id);
                };

                $scope.removeItem = function(id) {
                    PartnerService.removeItem(id);
                };
            }
        ]);

        app.factory('PartnerService', [
            '$firebase', 'FIREBASE_URI', function($firebase, FIREBASE_URI) {
                var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI);
                var items = $firebase(ref);

                var getItems = function() {
                    return items;
                };

                var addItem = function(item) {
                    items.$add(item);
                };

                var updateItem = function(id) {
                    items.$save(id);
                };

                var removeItem = function(id) {
                    items.$remove(id);
                };

                return {
                    getItems: getItems,
                    addItem: addItem,
                    updateItem: updateItem,
                    removeItem: removeItem
                }
            }
        ]);
    </script>

    <script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.15/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angularfire.min.js"></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

I have not been able to get the display values ({{item.Name}} -  {{item.OrigBal}}) to interpolate the data passed back by the service. I'm sure that it's something simple, but I'm obviously missing something essential. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: console.log is your friend

Comment: Shawn - console.log just gives me a cryptic error:  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…fc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55852%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387)

Comment: That occurs when you forget to include a module in your dependencies list. If you click on the error you'll be able to see which module. Please note that SO is not a debugging service. Do some due diligence here and clearly state the problem case with exact version info, error messages, and what you've tried to resolve them.

Comment: The version of Angular is 1.2.23, the AngularFire version is 0.8. When I click on the error in the console, I get: Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod]

MyApp is the name I assigned to ng-app, and this is why I'm confused. I do not see where I have left out a module in the dependencies list. Maybe putting the js in a file and not in a script tag, then referencing the js file would help me see it better, but as the code sits right now, I don't see what I have missed, though it's obvious that there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue was something simple and foolish. This line in javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('bastion', ['firebase']);
```

Then I defined my ng-app in HTML as:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
```

I changed to:

```
<html ng-app='bastion'>
```

and everything works correctly now.  Silly miss on my part, sorry for wasting anyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

```
var getItems = function() {
                    return items;
                };
```

should be

```
var getItems = function() {
                    return items.$asArray();
                };
```

Comment: changing to return items.$asArray(); didn't help.

Comment: changing to `return items.$asArray` was a correct comment, that was something else I needed to fix. Thank you.